# Question about the WMI Win32_WindowsProductActivation class and the SetProductKey method

Tags: vbscript, wmi

i have a question about the [`Win32_WindowsProductActivation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394520%28VS.85%29.aspx) WMI class and the  `SetProductKey` method.

when i run this code (vbscript) generated with the WMi Code creator, the execution fails with the error `Invalid parameter`

```
strComputer = "." 
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\CIMV2") 
' Obtain an instance of the the class 
' using a key property value.
Set objShare = objWMIService.Get("Win32_WindowsProductActivation")

' Obtain an InParameters object specific
' to the method.
Set objInParam = objShare.Methods_("SetProductKey"). _
    inParameters.SpawnInstance_()


' Add the input parameters.
objInParam.Properties_.Item("ProductKey") =  "QW4HDDQCRGHM64M6GJRK8K83T"

' Execute the method and obtain the return status.
' The OutParameters object in objOutParams
' is created by the provider.
Set objOutParams = objWMIService.ExecMethod("Win32_WindowsProductActivation", "SetProductKey", objInParam)

' List OutParams
Wscript.Echo "Out Parameters: "
Wscript.echo "ReturnValue: " & objOutParams.ReturnValue
```

but if i use this code works ok, using the `InstancesOf`  method.

```
Dim VOL_PROD_KEY
VOL_PROD_KEY =  "QW4HDDQCRGHM64M6GJRK8K83T"

for each Obj in GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}").InstancesOf ("win32_WindowsProductActivation")

result = Obj.SetProductKey (VOL_PROD_KEY)

if err &lt;&gt; 0 then
WScript.Echo Err.Description, "0x" &amp; Hex(Err.Number)
Err.Clear
end if

Next
```

the quiestions is

why the first code fails ?  or  why this wmi class  requires execute this method using the `InstancesOf`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must call and pass directly the parameters of `SetProductKey` method without use the `SpawnInstance_` because this method is **non-static**.

the rule is, if the wmi method to execute is static you can use the`SpawnInstance_` otherwise call the method passing directly the parameters

Here you have a description of static and non.static methods.

> Static methods apply only to WMI
>   classes and not to specific instances
>   of a class. For example, the Create
>   method of the Win32_Process class is a
>   static method because use it to create
>   a new process without an instance of
>   this class. Nonstatic methods apply
>   only to instances of a class. For
>   example, the Terminate method of the
>   Win32_Process class is a nonstatic
>   method because it only makes sense to
>   terminate a process if an instance of
>   that process exists. You can determine
>   if a method is static by checking if
>   the Static qualifier is associated
>   with the method.

Additionally you can check this article [`Calling a Provider Method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384833%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)